# Vue-autosuggest: How to get original context of the autosuggest component on select?

Tags: vue.js

I'm using the vue-autosuggest library inside of a for loop in my app.  In the autosuggest selected event, I am trying to determine *which* of the autosuggest (ie, what row) the selected applied to so that I can update other information on that row.  How do I get back to the original element in the for loop?

For example:

```
<tr v-for="lineindex, line in buylist.lines">
    <td class="image-column">
        <img v-if="line.image_url != ''" :src="line.image_url" class="img-thumbnail" :alt="line.sku">
    </td>
    <td class="sku-column"><vue-autosuggest
            v-model="line.sku" :suggestions="suggestions" :input-props="{placeholder:'Enter a SKU...', class:'form-control line-id'}" 
            :get-suggestion-value="getSku"
            @input="onInputChange" @selected="onSelected" @click="clickHandler">  
            <template slot-scope="{suggestion}">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center">
                    <div class="mr-4">
                        <img class="image" v-bind:src="suggestion.item.image_url">
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-grow-1">
                        <span class="item-description">{{ suggestion.item.description }}</span><br>
                        <span class="item-sku">{{ suggestion.item.sku }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="attribute-column">
                        <p class="attribute"><span class="attribute-value">{{ suggestion.item.category }}</span></p>
                        <p class="attribute"><span class="attribute-value">{{ suggestion.item.style }}</span></p>
                        <p class="attribute"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="attribute-column">
                        <p class="attribute"><span class="attribute-value">{{ suggestion.item.material }}</span></p>
                        <p class="attribute"><span class="attribute-value">{{ suggestion.item.grade }}</span></p>
                        <p class="attribute"><span class="attribute-value">{{ suggestion.item.size }}</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </template>
        </vue-autosuggest>
    </td>
</tr>
```

meanwhile, my suggestion objects are:

```
[
    {    
      'sku': 'Q6JAGA2OVB',
      'image_url': '03163637.jpg',
      'description': 'd1',
      'material': 'Silver',
      'style': 'd2',
      'size': '',
      'grade': 'AB',
      'category': 'd3',
    },
    {
      'sku': 'Q6JAHA2OVB',
      'image_url': '03133892.jpg',
      'description': 'd5',
      'material': 'Gold',
      'style': 'd6',
      'size': '',
      'grade': 'A',
      'category': 'd7',
    }
]
```

In the onSelected method, I want to update other attributes (for example, image-URL) on the "line" object with data from the selected suggestion.  I need access to either the object "line" or the value of "lineindex" so that I can somehow update the correct element in buylist.lines.  I was thinking even just the original input element for the autosuggest would work (I could just put the index attribute there).  As far as I can tell, the onSelected event only provides the suggestion and its index, but nothing about the component instance or its context.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar task. I don't know correctly solved it but I did like this.
I have added a prop in data object like this:

```
lastAutoSuggestFocused: null
```

and created a focus method for a autosuggest element:

```
doFocus(event){
    this.lastAutoSuggestFocused = event.target;
}
```

After it when an option are selecting I select lastAutoSuggestFocused:

```
onSelect(suggestion){
    const listId = this.lastAutoSuggestFocused.id;
    this.lastAutoSuggestFocused = null;
}
```

May do you have another a solve?